# Detaching a referenced record from a 1..N relationship, without deleting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a 1..N relationship between two classes

```
class A
  has_many: bees

class B
  belongs_to: a
```

I can add instances of B to `bees` collection without problem. 
When I try to remove a specific instance of B, by doing

```
a.bees.where( id: someid ).delete
```

then a gets deleted...

Also tried

```
   b.a.delete
```

with the same outcome
How do I just delete the relationship, leaving the instances intact?

Answer (score 0):

USe the [nullify](http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/master/Mongoid/Relations/Referenced/Many#nullify-instance_method) method.

Comment: do i have to use it on both sides of the relationship?

Comment: If I understand the method description in the link above correctly, then it removes the reference from both sides. You should have it covered in your tests, of course.